# How to compute the residual standard deviation from `glmer()` function in R?

Tags: r, self-study, logistic, generalized-linear-model, references

I want to extract standard deviation of residual from `glmer()` function in R .

So I wrote :

```
lmer_obj = glmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + (1|Subj), data=D, family=binomial)
sigma(lmer_obj)
```

I noticed that the last command `sigma(lmer_obj)` returns always `1` irrespective of the data That is, whether I used the `cbpp` data or my own simulated data from multilevel logistic distribution, the residual standard error is always `1`.

How can I get the residual standard deviation from `glmer()` function?

Comment: Please define "residual" first in the context of a logistic regression setting. Do you expect its standard deviation to be a single value, no matter the regressors?

Comment: @MichaelM In logistic regression $logit(\pi_i)=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i$ , I see  no residual  . But in two-level logistic regression model $logit(p_{ij})=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{10}x_{ij}+\gamma_{01}z_{j}+\gamma_{11}x_{ij}z_j+u_{0j}+u_{1j}x_{ij}$ , here variance of $u_{1j}$ is residual variance $\sigma_1^2$ , and I expect this to be a single value .

Comment: @MichaelM Could you please give me some reference in the context of your comment ?

Comment: Although asked in the context of R, this is really a conceptual misunderstanding about logistic regression & GLMMs. This Q should be considered on topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logistic regression models, whether they include random effects or not, do not have an error term (see: [Logistic Regression - Error Term and its Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124818/7290)).  This is generally true of most GLiMs (although linear regression is a special case of GLiMs and does have an error term).

Of course, given a predicted probability and an observed response value, various residuals can be formed (see: [Logistic regression and error terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/108114/7290)).  People naturally want to use these to assess their models, because that's what you do with linear models.  However, looking at these residuals will typically lead you astray (see: [Interpretation of plot(glm.model)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139624/7290)).

Thus, you are better off abandoning your quest for the standard deviation of the residuals, in my honest opinion.  That said, if you are dead set on this, you could try:

```
library(lme4)
data(cbpp)
m1 = glmer(cbind(incidence,size-incidence)~period+(1|herd), family=binomial, data=cbpp)
sd(residuals(m1, type="deviance"))  # [1] 1.133436
sd(residuals(m1, type="response"))  # [1] 0.1001946
```

---

*(Edit: the question is somewhat ambiguous.)*
If you want the estimated standard deviation of the population from which the sample was drawn, you could try:

```
attr(summary(m1)$varcor$herd, "stddev")
# (Intercept) 
#   0.6420699
```

If you want the standard deviation of the predicted random effects (these are not necessarily the same as above, see: [Why do the estimated values from a Best Linear Unbiased Predictor (BLUP) differ from a Best Linear Unbiased Estimator (BLUE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122587/7290)), you could try:

```
sd(ranef(m1)$herd[,1])  # [1] 0.5342242
```

If you are interested in the *dispersion*, it is almost always necessarily $1$ for logistic regression models.  If the response data are binomial with $n>1$ (i.e., not Bernoulli), you can have over- (or, less likely, under-) dispersion, but introducing the random effects here gets you back to $1$.  That piece of information is what the `sigma(m1)` is giving you (i.e., not the standard deviation of the residuals); you could also get it via:

```
summary(m1)$sigma  # [1] 1
```

Comment: A comment by the OP to the question leads me to suspect that `sigma(...)` is intended in a different way: namely, to obtain an estimate of the SD of a latent random component of this mixed model.

Comment: @whuber: it is used to measure under- or overdispersion (if quasibinomial etc. family was chosen). Maybe this is compatible with your comment?

Comment: @Michael Yes, that is what I thought Munira is looking for.  Munira: if that's the case, it would help to edit your question to explain precisely what you were hoping the `sigma` function would calculate.

Comment: A two-level logistic regression : $$\text{logit}(p_{ij})=\pi_{0j}+\pi_{1j} x_{ij}$$ $$\pi_{0j}=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{01}z_j+u_{0j}$$ $$\pi_{1j}=\gamma_{10}+\gamma_{11}z_j+u_{1j}$$
where ,$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        u_{0j} \\
        u_{1j} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=N
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma_0^2&\sigma_{01} \\
        \sigma_{01}&\sigma_1^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ .

Comment: @whuber  `lmer_obj = glmer(Y ~ X*Z + (1|cluster), data=D, family=binomial)`
I expected `attr(summary(lmer_obj)$varcor$herd, "stddev")` would calculate $\sigma_0$ and `sigma(lmer_obj)`  would calculate $\sigma_1$ .

Comment: Still I am not understanding how can I calculate $\sigma_1$  ?

Comment: In your example with `cbpp` data , `summary(m1)$residuals` gives $56$ residual values . What are those actually if logistic regression do not have error term ?

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1432.

Comment: @Munira, please read the linked threads. You may also want to read this: [What is the difference between errors and residuals?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133391/7290) There are 56 residual values b/c there are 56 observations & 56 predicted probabilities. I used the `cbpp` example b/c you referred to it. Note that it does not have random slopes, $u_{1j}$, & thus no $\sigma_1$ (in your terms). It only has random intercepts, which you might call $\sigma_0$. At this point there is a distinction b/t the estimate of the population SD & the SD of the REs. Both are shown above.

Comment: That is ,    `sd(ranef(m1)$herd[,1])` calculates $\sigma_0$ .  Aren't I right ?

Comment: @Munira, it depends on what you mean by $\sigma_0$. The code you show calculates the sample SD of the predicted random effects. If you want the estimated SD of the population from which the sample was drawn, you need `attr(summary(m1)$varcor$herd, "stddev")`. Because predicted random effects are 'shrunk' towards 0, the former won't typically equal the latter. From your comment above with the model displayed with $\LaTeX$, I would guess you may be after the latter.

Comment: I have understood that `m1 = glmer(cbind(incidence,size-incidence)~period+(1|herd), family=binomial, data=cbpp)
` is a random intercept model . But in case of random slope model (model in which regression coefficients vary randomly between level 2 units , such as,  `lmer_obj = glmer(Y ~ X*Z + (1|cluster), data=D, family=binomial)`) , could you please tell  how can I extract the estimates of random slopes ? From one of my comments above with the model  displayed with latex , I am telling $u_{1j}$ as random slopes . `ranef(lmer_obj)` gives estimates of random intercept , i.e.,  $u_{0j}$ .

Comment: @Munira, I need access to the actual object--I need a reproducible example. In addition, simply asking for code is off topic here. If you are at the point where you understand the issues & just need code help, you should ask on [SO]. Having said that, the example for `?lmer` in the documentation has both a slope & an intercept `m1 = lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy)`. For that example, you would use `attr(summary(fm1)$varcor$Subject, "stddev")[2]`. To figure this out for yourself, notice that the number you want shows up in `summary(m1)`, so use `str(summary(m1))` to find it.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit : what is the difference between `m1 = lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy)` and `m1 = lmer(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject), sleepstudy)` , That is , in the `formula` if I use $1$ before vertical bar `(1|Subject)` , what does it mean  ?

Comment: @Munira, try: [R's lmer cheat-sheet](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13166/7290).

Comment: Would you please help a little bit that isn't `attr(summary(m1)$varcor$herd, "stddev")` point estimates of standard deviation of the random effect ?

Comment: Could you please tell me what is *estimated standard deviation of population* in general term ? Is it $s=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar x)^2$ ?

Comment: @Munira, I'm not sure I understand your questions. Are you asking what the difference between a population & a sample is? If so, [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/269/7290) may help you.